# unexpected extra backslash when reading data from stdout using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, hex, stdout, encode

i have a python source code (with name `source.py`)  that display some data like

```
b'testdata \xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00@\x00\......
```

on terminal.

i want to get this informations and save them on a variable, so i wrote this code :

```
import subprocess

    
batcmd= 'python3.8 source.py'
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
print (result)
```

output:

```
b'testdata \\xe3\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x1f\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x00\\......
```

problem is any `\` will duplicate **2 times!**

how i can solve this issue ?

> Notes :
>
> 1 - i can't edit source.py!  i can't Manipulation it, we can only read
> data from terminal.
>
> 2 - i recently used `_w_long_`  and then i edited my post and
> algorithm  , So if you see it in the comments, it's because and ignore it.
>
> 3- Stored data must remain in **bytes**

**UPDATE:**

i also tried :

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io,os


res = os.popen("decompyle3 start.py.pyc").read()
print (res)

print (res.encode('latin1'))
```

in this code : `print(res)`, will print this data **with type string** in output :

```
"b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00sV\x00\x00\x00e\x00e\x01d\x00d\x01\x84\x00d\x02d\x03d\x03d\x04d\x05d\x06d\x07d\x08d\td\x03d\x03d\nd\x0bd\x05d\x0cd\x08d\rd\x0ed\x0cd\x0fd\..."
```

so i want *convert this string to Byte* without any changing, i want this output :

```
b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00sV\x00\x00\x00e\x00e\x01d\x00d\x01\x84\x00d\x02d\x03d\x03d\x04d\x05d\x06d\x07d\x08d\td\x03d\x03d\nd\x0bd\x05d\x0cd\x08d\rd\x0ed\x0cd\x0fd\...
```

i tried :

```
print (res.encode('latin1'))
```

that printed  :

```
b\'\\xe3\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x1f\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x00\\x00\\x00sV\\x00\\x00\\x00e\\x00e\\x01d\\x00d\\x01\\x84\\x00d\\x02d\\x03d\\x03d\\x04d\\x05d\\x06d\\x07d\\x08d\\td\\x03d\\x03d\\nd\\x0bd\\x05d\\x0cd\\x08d\\rd\\x0ed\\x0cd\\x0fd...
```

As we see any `\` duplicated !

how solve this problem?

Comment: [The `marshal` format changes from version to version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html): "the Python maintainers reserve the right to modify the marshal format in backward incompatible ways should the need arise." So something `marshal`ed in version `X.Y` has no guarantees of being unmarshallable in version `X.Y+1` (or vice-versa). Why would you expect it to work without alteration in all versions of Python?

Comment: yes marshal format and algorithms is changing , but what about _w_long lib ? is this lib doesn't exist in python3.8 and higher?

Comment: `_w_long` is an internal implementation detail (you can tell by the leading underscore). It wasn't guaranteed to stay, no one is supposed to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io,os

with io.StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf):
    os.system("python3.8 source.py")
    res = buf.getvalue()
    print(res)
```

Comment: this script only Fetch stdout. , i already used `subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)` for fetch that . my problem is convert this fetched string to byte with any dumplication in `\\`